# How to Bind DataGridView with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-2008-express

Can anyone help me in this Code Please. I am trying to bind data with datagridview. Query is returning values in sql server. But it's not binding any value in DataGridView....

```
     private void CheckMembers()
     {
        try
        {
            string query = "Select id, id-no, status From Members Where Head=@Head";

            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Head", "2288885858");
            sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                fmGview.Visible = true;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(sqlDataReader);
                MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
                fmGview.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString(), "Exception in CheckMembers");
        }
        finally
        {
            CheckConnectionStatus();
        }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: This should work i think. Are you sure your sql find some data?

Comment: i tested your code. it works fine. maybe your fieldname on grid has a typo or something.

Comment: Anyone else please ? No Success Yet

Comment: if you double-checked and `dt` is not empty, please also post yout UI code. DataGridView doesn't belong to wpf

Comment: @ASh, I have a datagridview with 4 columns. But i am trying to bind only one column. Is it the problem ?

Comment: @MistrMowgli, i don't know. you didn't show any UI code

Comment: @ASh, there is no specific code. Only on runtime i am trying to bind datagridview

Comment: How do you know you have connected to the db? Try strong typed value for @Head and see if you get anything back

Comment: @Daniel, even then it is not binding with DataGridView

Comment: @Daniel, i have 4 columns that need to show. One is Serial Number, Id, Permission Status and last Column is for Link {Delete}

Comment: I now but first eliminate the stupidest solutions and then the rest of them.
Where is the column called Head ?

Comment: @Daniel, See my edited post now

Comment: @MistrMowgli How many rows are in `dt`? Please change your MessageBox call so it look exactly like this: `MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " is the count of rows in dt");`

Comment: @EdPlunkett, `3 in the counter of rows in dt`

Comment: @MistrMowgli Please go into the VS form designer for your form, click on `fmGview` in the form designer, and go to the "Properties" pane. Select the "Columns" row in "Properties", and click on the "..." button by where it says "**(Collection)**". Then take a screenshot using `ALT+PrtScr` and add the screenshot to your question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Picture added. Pls check edited post now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `DataPropertyName` for each column in the Columns designer. You do this by putting the mouse pointer over the right hand cell in the `DataPropertyName` row, where it says **(none)**, and clicking the left mouse button. Select the text that says "(none)", and type the database field name that you want to be displayed in that `DataGridView` column.

Comment: Click the mouse in the box and type the name of the field. In the one that you want to be `id`, type "id".

Comment: It start inserting blank rows only

Comment: @MistrMowgli What did you type in that box?

Comment: ...Yes Man u did it... i got it :)

Comment: Is it directly bind with database now ? I mean if i will update anything in datagridview it will be automatically update in database or should i safe again ?

Comment: I don't think so. [This code shows how to send `DataTable` changes back to the SQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293977/424129).

Comment: Thanks for helping... Really Appreciated