# Expression between datatable values using C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable

i want to declare mathematical expression between values from datatable , for example: i have two columns named 'Variable'(string) and 'Contents' (float) , i have inserted in 'Variables' 3 string a , b and c and in 'Contents' 3 floats are 0, 3 and 6 .Now i want to declare 'a=b+c' in code an when i click on a 'button' the variable a will change in datatable to 9. here is my code but it doesn't work!! help me please !

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();            
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table_sagemcom ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataRow dr1 = dt.Select("Variable='a'").FirstOrDefault();
        DataRow dr2 = dt.Select("Variable='b'").FirstOrDefault();
        DataRow dr3 = dt.Select("Variable='c'").FirstOrDefault();

        dr1["Contents"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr2["Contents"]) + Convert.ToDouble(dr3["Contents"]);

        ds1.Tables.Add(dt);

        con.Close();}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work!! " is not clear. Does your code throws an exceptions? Does it run but some variable's got unexpected value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update database with changes made to DataTable... confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273057/update-database-with-changes-made-to-datatable-confusion)

Comment: @Serg it runs but Nothing is happening th value of 'a' in the table remains unchanged always ='0'

Comment: @Eugene Podskal  can you look at my edited answer again !

Comment: @Aseljo It probably means that something either at `dt.Rows[1]["Variable"]` or `dt.Rows[2]["Variable"]` is not a valid `double`. In any case, without  having a full exception stacktrace and knowing the exact contents of those cells, we can only guess.

Comment: @EugenePodskal i I wished that i could find the position of  Contents through the names of Variable 'a' , 'b'  and 'c' but that solution works with index of rows!! i edited my answer again !

Comment: There are a lot of info on such an error - https://www.google.com/search?q=System.InvalidOperationException%3A+%27The+dynamic+SQL+generation+of+UpdateCommand+is+not+supported+for+a+SelectCommand+that+does+not+return+key+column+information&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruRU862RU862&oq=System.InvalidOperationException%3A+%27The+dynamic+SQL+generation+of+UpdateCommand+is+not+supported+for+a+SelectCommand+that+does+not+return+key+column+information Have you tried any of the suggestions?

Comment: @Eugene Podskal i tried to solve that error but i fail :(

Comment: That does not tell us what you have tried and how it failed. I recommend you to rewrite the question leaving only the final version of the code and describe what you have tried to solve `The dynamic SQL generation of UpdateCommand is not supported` and how it fails.

Comment: @EugenePodskal   i edited my answer just now with my last code and Always datatable still unchanged when i run my code and no errors occured  !

Comment: Probably because you have lost the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293977/3745022 (first comment) . Now there is nothing that actually saves the dataset, so no changes. Well, I recommend to go one step down and try to make the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293977/3745022 actually work for you (I mean the **exact** code without any `Convert.ToDouble(dr2["Contents"]) +` - just plain 1. get data 2. change row 3 save dataset 4. Check that it works). Do not try to solve everything in one go (even when you have some experience and especially if not) - solve everything step by step.

Comment: @EugenePdskal yes i tried that code and it shows me an error that i should declare a primary key System.InvalidOperationException: 'The dynamic SQL generation of UpdateCommand is not supported for a SelectCommand that does not return key column information.' so what should i add in my SQL line to select the primary key?!!!